# Error : composition Complete Callbacks[i] is not a function in Durandal 2.0

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, durandal

I'm getting an JavaScript Error saying,

> "composition Complete Callbacks[i] is not a function"

I'm using Durandal 2.0 and have implemented compositionComplete Method in one page like this,

```
 var compositionComplete = function () {
    viewModel.valueHasMutated();
 };
```

does anyone know what has gone wrong?

Comment: Can you add the code of the function `valueHasMutated` ?

Comment: @margabit: it's a predefined function in knockout.js to notify that viewModel is updated.

Comment: What is `viewModel`? An observable? An object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is found few days ago. Here 'viewModel' was not an observable. It was a result of an ajax call. I mapped it into an observable using knockout mapping plugin and problem is solved.